# Odd behaviour Google fusion table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am wondering why I am receiving the following error:

TypeError: e.row.beachID is undefined

My click event handler works as expected, but my mouseover and mouseout event handler although similar to the click handler outputs the TypeError message noted above. If I am able to retrieve layer data from gft using the 'click handler' than why can't I do the same with 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' handler - I am trying to retrieve data from the same table.

```
/* start map initialization  */
function initialize() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.894634, -97.119141);
    var myOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            ],

            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: true
        }

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'POINT',
            from: tableID
        },
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    // begin tooltip section
    layer.enableMapTips({
        select: "'beachID', 'beach'",
        from: tableID,
        geometryColumn: 'POINT',
        suppressMapTips: true,
        delay: 100,
        tolerance: 8
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseover', function (e) {
        $('#info').html(
            '<h3>' + e.row['beachID'].value + '</h3>',
            '<h3>' + e.row['beach'].value + '</h3>');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseout', function (e) {
        $('#info').html('<h2>Mouseout</h2>') ;
    });
    // end tooltip section


    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (e) {
        // close infoWindow if open
        if (infoWindow) {
            infoWindow.close();
        }
        beachID = e.row['beachID'].value;
        beachName = e.row['beach'].value;
        point = e.row['POINT'].value;
        region = e.row['region'].value;
        sampleDate = e.row['Date'].value;
        ecoli_count = e.row['avg_ecoli_count'].value;
        water_quality_guideline = e.row['water_quality_guideline'].value; 
    });
}
```

Is there something obvious that I missed? Any thoughts are always appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

The only valid event on a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesLayer) is a click:

click | FusionTablesMouseEvent | This event is fired when a feature in the layer is clicked.

That returns a [FusionTablesMouseEvent object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent)